# How to change default shell in iTerm2 via command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, iterm2

### How to change iTerm2 shell via CLI?

I want to change the user's iTerm2 preferences.

1. I've taken a snapshot of iTerm2's preferences:

   ```bsh
   defaults read com.googlecode.iTerm2 > iTerm2.original.defaults
   ```
2. Then I've changed them in the GUI:
   [image: iTerm2 Custom Shell]
3. And then I've made another snapshot:

   ```bsh
   defaults read com.googlecode.iTerm2 > iTerm2.updated.defaults
   ```
4. I can see that the difference is in "New Bookmarks" (though this seems like a rather odd name for a preference change...):

   ```
   {
       ...
       "New Bookmarks" =     (
           {
           ...
           Command = "/Users/aj/.local/bin/fish";
           "Custom Command" = "Custom Shell";
       )
   }
   ```

I have no idea how I can change an array like that - or if it's even possible with the `defaults` command. Is there another way?

### For reference

I do know how to do this with Terminal.app and with Unix commands. That's NOT what I'm looking for.

I do NOT want to change `/etc/shells` and `etc/passwd`.

I've also opened an issue about this at https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9151

#### Changing the Shell in Terminal.app

```bsh
defaults write com.apple.Terminal "Shell" -string "/Users/me/.local/bin/fish"
```

#### Changing the user's default Shell

```bsh
MY_FISH="$(which fish)"
if ! grep "$MY_FISH" /etc/shells; then
    sudo 'bash echo "$MY_FISH" >> /etc/shells'
fi
sudo chsh -s "$(which fish)" "$(whoami)"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### plutil and PlistBuddy

`plutil` can be used to extract the current values and `PlistBuddy` can be used to write new ones.

Using plutil and PlistBuddy I was able to determine that "New Bookmarks" IS where the profile preferences are saved.

plutil

```bsh
plutil -extract "New Bookmarks".0."Command" xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>/Users/aj/.local/bin/fish</string>
</plist>
```

```bsh
plutil -extract "New Bookmarks".0."Custom Command" xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>Custom Shell</string>
</plist>
```

PlistBuddy

```bsh
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "SET ':New Bookmarks:0:Custom Command' 'Custom Shell'" ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```

```bsh
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "SET ':New Bookmarks:0:Command' $HOME/.local/bin/fish" ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```